# unable to receive the push notification in foreground using FCM

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to get firebase push-notification in my app. I have tried everything on the internet but couldn't find solution. I have been receiving notification in background, but when App is in foreground I am unable to get the notification. But when I print the userInfo in "didReceiveRemoteNotification" I get the message in console
Any help would be appreciated.

```
import Firebase
import UserNotifications


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    //FirebaseApp.configure()

    self.initializeFCM(application)
    let token = InstanceID.instanceID().token()
    debugPrint("GCM TOKEN = \(String(describing: token))")

    return true
}

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error)
{
    debugPrint("didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: \(error)")
}

func application(received remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage)
{
    debugPrint("remoteMessage:\(remoteMessage.appData)")
}

func initializeFCM(_ application: UIApplication)
{
    print("initializeFCM")

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) // enable new way for notifications on iOS 10
    {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert , .sound]) { (accepted, error) in
            if !accepted
            {
                print("Notification access denied.")
            }
            else
            {
                print("Notification access accepted.")
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        let type: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.sound];
        let setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: type, categories: nil);
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(setting);
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications();
    }

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true

}

// enable new way for notifications on iOS 10

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegister notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings)
{
    debugPrint("didRegister notificationSettings")
    if (notificationSettings.types == .alert || notificationSettings.types == .badge || notificationSettings.types == .sound)
    {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}


func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)
{
    debugPrint("didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: NSDATA")

    let token = String(format: "%@", deviceToken as CVarArg)
    debugPrint("*** deviceToken: \(token)")

    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken as Data
    debugPrint("Firebase Token:",InstanceID.instanceID().token() as Any)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)
{
    debugPrint("didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: DATA")
    let token = String(format: "%@", deviceToken as CVarArg)
    debugPrint("*** deviceToken: \(token)")

    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    debugPrint("Firebase Token:",InstanceID.instanceID().token() as Any)
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------//

// [START receive_message]
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    print(userInfo)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
// [END receive_message]

}


// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
 }
}
 // [END ios_10_message_handling]

 extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
// [START refresh_token]
 func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
}
// [END ios_10_data_message]
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Since iOS 14**, `.alert` is deprecated, you might use `.banner` instead:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let content = notification.request.content
    // Process notification content
    print("\(content.userInfo)")
    completionHandler([.banner, .list, .sound]) // Display notification Banner     
}
```

---

**From iOS 10,** You can display Apple's default notification banner using below function.
Notification behaviour will depend on properties which you return within completionHandler.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let content = notification.request.content
    // Process notification content
    print("\(content.userInfo)")
    completionHandler([.alert, .sound]) // Display notification Banner
}
```

**As per details in your question, you have already implemented above function, but with blank completionHandler(). Because of that notification banner doesn't display while app is in foreground state.**

**Earlier iOS 10:**

You need to handle this by yourself. Like if you want to display banner when you received a notification, while app is in foreground state. You need to do this by yourself. You have to design your custom notification banner to display within app.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: i am stll unable to receive the notification is foreground, can you please tell me how to design custom notification banner.

Comment: You are testing this in iOS 10 or lower ?

Comment: To create Custom Notification Banner, check this repository https://github.com/Daltron/NotificationBanner and many more available on github.

Comment: ohh.. that must be because of i'm testing app on IOS 9.3.5

Comment: Yes, In lower than  iOS 10, you have to use custom banner to display banner while app is in foreground state.

Comment: :)   @kunalkushwaha

Comment: will there be same issue for receiving the local notification in foreground?

Comment: Yes, It will be same.

Comment: thanks it worked having issue of completionHandler() with blank

Answer (score 4):

1. Add this func in your AppDelegate:

   ```
   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
       completionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge])
   }
   ```
2. Add UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate protocol to your AppDelegate class like this:

   ```
   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
   ```
3. Add below line in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions func:

   ```
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
   ```