# Listening for changes in Firestore database in and out of the App - Swift

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to listen for update on the client side whenever something in the `Firestore` database changes.
I need some clarification about this topic:

Let's say that we want to notify the user whenever a new document is created in a collection:
We have 2 cases:

1. when the user is on the app
2. when the user is out of the app

for the second point I can create a `cloud function firestore trigger` that notifies the user through the `push notification service`

But on the first point I don't know which is the best approach.

(maybe setting up a snapshotListener? but how can I do that on the global scope of the app? Is it the right approach?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you implement a FCM notification for the second scenario, the notification will be fired to your app no matter if it is on background or foreground, so you can use this approach for both situations actually.

You can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44939581/12857703) to not fire a notification (on the frontend) and in case you don't want to fire that if the app is in foreground you can just keep the `completionHandler()` blank and that's it.

Comment: thank you, but instead of the completion handler can I perform some operations in the UI? like presenting some custom banner

Comment: yes, you can. you can do any operation needed in fact, the mentioned code is just to show or not show the notification itself.

Comment: That's perfect thank you, one more thing, Is there a way I can get the content of the notification inside ```willPresent notification``` delegate function?

Comment: I believe all you need to do is this: `let content = notification.request.content`

Comment: Thank you very much, accepted answer, really appreciated your help 

Comment: glad to be of help :)